# Unable to select an option from a drop down in Katalon studio

Tags: select, katalon-studio

I am new to Katalon Studio and I am facing an issue regarding selection of the drop down.
Please find below the details:
This is the HTML :
[image]

I have tried using selectByIndex with the object xpath as:
`//div[@class='paCriteriaContainer']//select[@class = 'pa-criteria-select a-select  initialized']`

It does not select any option and fails with an error stating "Unable to select option by index '2' of object"

Note:

1. I tried clicking on the input and then selecting the option, but that doesn't seem to work either.
2. Selecting by label and value don't work either

Please help me here.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try to capture an object and then use following methods :

```
WebUI.click(findTestObject(Your captured object))

WebUI.selectOptionByValue(findTestObject(Your captured object), 'TEST (2020)', false)
```

Did you done as I've described and it does not work ?

Comment: Can you post what are you using exactly and also error message ?

Answer (score 0):

> I tried clicking on the input and then selecting the option, but that doesn't seem to work either.

Are you sure you are clicking the right element in this case?

Try the following instead: create programmatically the element and select by value (note, value isn't the text contained, it is the `value` html attribute):

```
TestObject to = new TestObject().addProperty("xpath", ConditionType.EQUALS, "//div[@class='paCriteriaContainer']//select[@class = 'pa-criteria-select a-select  initialized']")
WebUI.selectOptionByValue(to, '40696', false)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some options to do that, I reggardly suggest you that use always the xpath to reach all the elements that you want to use. The reasson is because the object reports usually fail and, in my opinion, this way is so much more complicated.
But obviously, the xpath will change if the web do, so take care with it.

```
The imports you need:
import static org.junit.Assert.*
import org.openqa.selenium.By
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys
import com.kms.katalon.core.webui.driver.DriverFactory as DriverFactory

def driver = DriverFactory.getWebDriver()

//If you want to click your input would be:
WebUI.click(WebUI.convertWebElementToTestObject(driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@id='a-select-paCricteriaId_6908'])"))))

//**you just can click on "TestObject" type, and findElement returns "Element" type**
```

And if you want to select the option you need to know the whole path (I cannot get it with the given information).

An important tip for testing the xpath is to use this function in console mode (F12):

```
function getElementByXpath(path) {
    return document.evaluate(path, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
}

//And this code in the same console to test your xpath:
getElementByXpath("YOURTESTXPATH")
```

Furthermore, there are other ways to reach the same objetive with xpath, for example:

```
import com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.TestObject as TestObject
...
TestObject tobj = new TestObject('myTestObject')
String expr = '/some/valid/xpath/expression'
tobj.addProperty('xpath', ConditionType.EQUALS, expr)
WebUI.click(tobj)
```

You have a lot of information if you google "how to get elements by xpath katalon".

Here you can get official information about it:
https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/tutorials/detect_elements_xpath.html#what-is-xpath

Answer (score 0):

Test in the browser console

```
$x('//*[contains(@class, "pa-criteria-select a-select  initialized")]')
```

if more than one result appear then you can access it like this

```
$x('(//*[contains(@class, "pa-criteria-select a-select  initialized")])[1]')
```

then you can also access their children

```
$x('(//*[contains(@class, "pa-criteria-select a-select  initialized")])[1]/option')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `WebUI.selectOptionByIndex` keyword but the object should point to the select tag instead of the div.
Update the object element and your code should work